# How to add Show / Hide Editor for custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.1.3

I am created product custom `attribute`(specification) and which is showing perfect. Now I am looking for add the **Show / Hide Editor** for my custom field.
[image]

Any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this custom attribute, You should enable  `wysiwyg editor`.

### Solution1: from admin

If your attribute product attribute then goto admin>Store>Attribute>Product

Select your attribute goto tab>Storefront Properties>Enable WYSIWYG
*Make this value*  to **`Yes`**

[image]

### Solution2 : Using UpgradeData script

If you  create this custom attribute using  setup script then  also using  create an  ***updatedata script*** then using  make `'wysiwyg_enabled' => true` for attribute.

**UpgradeData  setup file is:**

================

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[MOduleName]\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Upgrade Data script
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory, EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup= $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
            ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
            '[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]',
            [
               'wysiwyg_enabled' => true
            ]
        );
         $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case Amit Bera solution doesn't work. Try mine:

Instead of:

```
    $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
        ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
        '[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]',
        [
           'wysiwyg_enabled' => true
        ]
    );
```

use:

```
    $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
        ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
        '[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]',
        'is_wysiwyg_enabled',
         false
    );
```